# C# Winform MySql Update Button error (it's update all records)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, button, sql-update

**UPDATE**: Problem solved; dear all with your help i just realized the problem and first i added ID column from db to datagridview as well i added a textbox to my formdesing. After that i just put "where" and "id" condition as below. Thanks you all!

```
string Query = "update doguAkdenizApp.team set id='" + this.txtEkipKayitNo.Text + "', name='" + this.txtEkipIsim.Text + "', surname='" + this.txtEkipSoyisim.Text + "', birth='" + this.dtpEkipDogum.Text + "', telephone='" + this.txtEkipTelefon.Text + "', email='" + this.txtEkipEposta.Text + "', city='" + this.cbEkipSehir.Text + "', adress='" + this.txtEkipAdres.Text + "', recorddate='"+this.dtpEkipDogum.Text+ "' where id='" + this.txtEkipKayitNo.Text + "';";
```

I am having problem with code block below, I am using an "Update" button to edit selected row's data but unfortunetly it's update whole records inserted to database.

How can i arrenge the code for only selected row?

```
 private void btnEkipGuncelle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   string myConnection = "datasource=root;port=root;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "update doguAkdenizApp.team set name='" + this.txtEkipIsim.Text + "', surname='" + this.txtEkipSoyisim.Text + "', birth='" + this.dtpEkipDogum.Text + "', telephone='" + this.txtEkipTelefon.Text + "', email='" + this.txtEkipEposta.Text + "', city='" + this.cbEkipSehir.Text + "', adress='" + this.txtEkipAdres.Text + "', recorddate='"+this.dtpEkipDogum.Text+"';";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Güncelleme başarılı!"); //Update success notification
            while (myReader.Read()) { }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        loadTable();
        clearAllTxt();*/
    }
```

Thanks a lot, Nuri.

Comment: That is not the correct way to build a SQL query.  It is very problematic and its simply is not that tedious to perform DB Ops.

Comment: Dear @Plutonix is there any better query? To update only for selected row on datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update doguAkdenizApp.team set name='' where some condition
```

You forgot the where condition.
Right now you write to update the whole rows in the table, if you will add a where condition like `where id = 3`, then only the row with id (only for example) will be update

Comment: So how can i let the application to understand which record user selected?

Answer (score 0):

This is related purely to SQL, You are calling this SQL query:

```
string Query = "update doguAkdenizApp.team set name='" + this.txtEkipIsim.Text + "', surname='" + this.txtEkipSoyisim.Text + "', birth='" + this.dtpEkipDogum.Text + "', telephone='" + this.txtEkipTelefon.Text + "', email='" + this.txtEkipEposta.Text + "', city='" + this.cbEkipSehir.Text + "', adress='" + this.txtEkipAdres.Text + "', recorddate='"+this.dtpEkipDogum.Text+"';";
```

SQL will first select all the rows You want to update, then do the update and as last commit all the changes to DB. What does it do in Your example? It will select all the entries (as condition is missing) and then it will update all the entries.

**It should look like:**

```
string Q = "UPDATE doguAkdenizApp.team set /* all the set*/ WHERE surname='"+this.txtEkipSoyisim.Text+"'";
```

Comment: Dear Tatran so it will update only selected row if i'll use only a column? Did i get right?

Comment: It will update all the rows based on the condition (which is put in `WHERE` clause). You can update any column, but all values You will specify, will be update. The others (which won't be entered) will be ignored.